# athena / presto query

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a json saved in Athena table like

```
{
    "VALIDATION_TYPE": "ROW_BY_ROW",
    "DATABASE": "erp",
    "TABLES": {
        "APPLICATION_STATUS_TYPE": {
            "BATCH_VALIDATION": {
                "BATCHES": [{
                    "0": {
                        "FAILED": "FALSE",
                        "FAILURE_MSG": ""
                    }
                }, {
                    "1": {
                        "FAILED": "TRUE",
                        "FAILURE_MSG": "NULL POINTER EXCEPTION"
                    }

                }]
            }
        },
        "APPLICATION": {
            "BATCH_VALIDATION": {
                "BATCHES": [{
                    "0": {
                        "FAILED": "FALSE",
                        "FAILURE_MSG": ""
                    }
                }, {
                    "1": {
                        "FAILED": "TRUE",
                        "FAILURE_MSG": "NULL POINTER EXCEPTION"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to write a query in Athena to find,  find all the FAILED=TRUE records like below

**output:**

```
VALIDATION_TYPE,DATABASE,TABLE,ID,FAILED,FAILURE,FAIURE_MSG
----------------------------------------------------
ROW_BY_ROW,erp,APPLICATION_STATUS_TYPE,1,TRUE,NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
ROW_BY_ROW,erp,APPLICATION,1,TRUE,NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
```

I have tried various functions like TRANSFORM,UNNEST,JSON_EXTRACT  etc , but no luck yet. Please advise if there are any specific functions I can use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick which can be used is to cast some json parts as `map(varchar, something)` and/or `array`'s:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(json_val) as (
    values (json '{
    "VALIDATION_TYPE": "ROW_BY_ROW",
    "DATABASE": "erp",
    "TABLES": {
        "APPLICATION_STATUS_TYPE": {
            "BATCH_VALIDATION": {
                "BATCHES": [{
                    "0": {
                        "FAILED": "FALSE",
                        "FAILURE_MSG": ""
                    }
                }, {
                    "1": {
                        "FAILED": "TRUE",
                        "FAILURE_MSG": "NULL POINTER EXCEPTION"
                    }

                }]
            }
        },
        "APPLICATION": {
            "BATCH_VALIDATION": {
                "BATCHES": [{
                    "0": {
                        "FAILED": "FALSE",
                        "FAILURE_MSG": ""
                    }
                }, {
                    "1": {
                        "FAILED": "TRUE",
                        "FAILURE_MSG": "NULL POINTER EXCEPTION"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}')
)
```

```sql
-- query
select json_extract_scalar(json_val, '$.VALIDATION_TYPE') VALIDATION_TYPE,
       json_extract_scalar(json_val, '$.DATABASE') DATABASE,
       t1.k "TABLE",
       t3.k ID,
       t3.map_v['FAILED'] FAILED,
       t3.map_v['FAILURE_MSG'] FAILURE_MSG
from dataset
, unnest(cast(json_extract(json_val, '$.TABLES') as map(varchar, json))) as t1(k, v)
, unnest(cast(json_extract(t1.v, '$.BATCH_VALIDATION.BATCHES') as array(map(varchar, map(varchar, json))))) as t2(m)
, unnest(t2.m) as t3(k, map_v);
```

Output:

| VALIDATION_TYPE | DATABASE | TABLE | ID | FAILED | FAILURE_MSG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ROW_BY_ROW | erp | APPLICATION | 0 | FALSE |  |
| ROW_BY_ROW | erp | APPLICATION | 1 | TRUE | NULL POINTER EXCEPTION |
| ROW_BY_ROW | erp | APPLICATION_STATUS_TYPE | 0 | FALSE |  |
| ROW_BY_ROW | erp | APPLICATION_STATUS_TYPE | 1 | TRUE | NULL POINTER EXCEPTION |

And then you can apply the filtering.

Comment: thanks @Guru Stron, perfect ,  is there a way I can hook a table to this instead of with dataset(json_val) ?, I am trying on my side as well.

Comment: @Bill of course, you should just change `from dataset` to `from your_table_name` and CTE `with dataset ...` is not needed at all - it is just test data.